# How to query by multiple sub table conditions to get the main table and sub table data list？

Tags: mysql, sql, mybatis

Example:

Have three table: person、attr、attr_value.

person's columns:id,sex ...

attr's colunms:id,name ...

attr_value's columns:person_id,attr_id,value

Have a `Map<Interger,String>` map **filters**:

key(attr_id),value

`1,Tom`

`2,female`

...

my sql(mybatis):

```
SELECT ...
FROM person p
INNER JOIN  attr_value v ON v.person_id =p.id
WHERE
p.logic_del=1
<if test="filters!=null and filters.size()>0">
        <foreach index="key" item="value" collection="filters.entrySet()" >
            AND EXISTS(
                SELECT 1 FROM  attr_value
                WHERE
                person_id =p.id
                AND attr_id= #{key}
                AND value  LIKE CONCAT('%',${value},'%')
            )
        </foreach>
</if>
```

generate  sql like:

```
SELECT ...
FROM person p
INNER JOIN  attr_value v ON v.person_id =p.id
WHERE
p.logic_del=1
AND EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM  attr_value
    WHERE
    person_id =p.id
    AND attr_id= 1
    AND value  LIKE CONCAT('%','Tom','%')
)
AND EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM  attr_value
    WHERE
    person_id =p.id
    AND attr_id= 2
    AND value  LIKE CONCAT('%','female','%')
)
...
```

Maybe my SQL can be optimized？Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: I want to optimize my sql.

Comment: As well as SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables, questions about query performance always require the EXPLAIN for the given query

Answer (score 0):

If you want your query to run faster, you should created indexes on:

- `attr_value(person_id, attr_id, value)`
- `person(logic_del, id)`  -- and perhaps other columns as well depending on the query

The first is more important.

Comment: I  added indexes.